# Johansen Test - Full rank but variables are not I(0)

Tags: stationarity, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have a model of four implied exchange rates which are based on stock prices denominated in two currencies. They should all be cointegrated based on the law of one price.

Each of the series is clearly I(1) based on ADF-testing, even when adding constant/trend terms. When using Johansen's test, I attain a matrix $\Pi$ of full rank. According to text books this should imply that the underlying data is I(0) and no Error Correction Model is needed as the data is already stationary. However as mentioned, the ADF clearly stated that it is non-stationary.

I'd appreciate your comment on that. Thank you!

Comment: A nonrejection of a test is very certainly not a "clear" statement that the corresponding null hypothesis is true!

Comment: What do you propose?

Comment: Indeed, I haven't proposed anything, just alerted you to the possibility that the tests in your analysis may make mistakes.

Comment: @ChristophHanck if the conclusion is that the Matrix is full rank it is because you are indeed rejecting all the null hypothesis in every Johansen's test step, so I don't get your point

Comment: Well, an ADF test indicating that the series "clearly" are I(1) might just suffer from low power in rejecting the unit root null.